# SQLite with CodeName One

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, codenameone

I have developed a application using the CodeName One plugin for Java in the Netbeans IDE.

CodeName One uses the Database API. https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html

```
Database db = null;
Cursor cur = null;
String Fname = findTxtFirstn(c).getText();
String Lname = findTxtLastn(c).getText();

try{

    Database ARdb = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("RecordsDB.db");            
    System.out.println("Connection secured to database.");
    String query = "insert into RecordsTable (First_Name,Last_Name) values (Fname,Lname)";           

    ARdb.execute(query);

} catch(Exception e){

    System.out.println("Error! Connection Failed to DB" +e.getMessage());

} finally {

    Util.cleanup (db);
    Util.cleanup(cur);

}
```

I have connected to the Database I created externally using DB Browser for SQLite. I have run the following queries in the DB Browser:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = "1";
SELECT type,name,sql,tbl_name,'0' AS temp FROM sqlite_master UNION SELECT type,name,sql,tbl_name,'1' AS temp FROM sqlite_temp_master;
PRAGMA encoding
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC);
SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC LIMIT 0, 50000;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC);
SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC LIMIT 0, 50000;
INSERT INTO `RecordsTable`(`ID`,`First_Name`,`Last_Name`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Street`,`Town`,`Postcode`,`Dog_Name`,`Breed`,`Age`,`Gender`,`BIO`) VALUES (1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `First_Name`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Last_Name`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
PRAGMA foreign_keys
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC);
SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC LIMIT 0, 50000;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC);
SELECT `_rowid_`,* FROM `RecordsTable` ORDER BY `_rowid_` ASC LIMIT 0, 50000;
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Phone`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `First_Name`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Phone`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Email`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Street`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Town`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
UPDATE `RecordsTable` SET `Postcode`=? WHERE _rowid_='1';
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code to update the database from my mobile application I get an SQL error:

```
Connection secured to database.
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: RecordsTable)
Error! Connection Failed to DB[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: RecordsTable)
```

The name of the Database is correct (connection has been made), however, it won't acknowledge the table.

Comment: The page you link to shows several overrides of the `execute` function to execute queries against the database. Did you even read it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problematic potion is the insert vs. select statement?

You can do an insert with parameters using:

```
ARdb.execute(query, valueOne, valueTwo);
```

Comment: Oh yea. I see it now, thank you! I subscribed to your YouTube channel. The issue I'm having now is an SQL error - updating question.

Comment: You need to run an SQL create statement first. FYI in cases like this just post a new question. You should revise questions for clarity/missing information and post new questions for a different problem. I know it's a fine line sometimes but when in doubt just add a new one ;-)